# AnalysisException: No such struct field x in

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

I am trying to parse a json using pyspark. I know for sure that there's 1 row after filtering.

```
def compute(violations, events, ctx):

    df = events.dataframe()
    
    df = df.filter(F.col("failure_class") == "size_violation")

    json_schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.data)).schema
    df = df.withColumn('data', F.from_json(F.col('data'), json_schema))
    df = df.withColumn("failure", F.col("data.failure"))
```

The row values inside the **data** column look like this:

```
{"failure":{"actualSizeBytes":206958,"expectation":"oversized collector payload: cannot split POST requests which are not json expected json value got '<?xml ...' (line 1, column 1)","maximumAllowedSizeBytes":192000,"timestamp":"2023-10-05T23:18:38.23456Z"},"payload":"CollectorPayload(schema:iglu:com.xxxx.xxx/CollectorPayload/thrift/1-0-0, ......
```

First, I convert the string type to a struct type. Then, I try to read the "data.failure" into a different column but I keep getting this error:

pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: No such struct field failure in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transforms_spark_module/delegate.py", line 97, in _execute_job
    outputs = job.run(input_specs,
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transforms/_build.py", line 248, in run
    self._transform.compute(ctx=transform_context, **parameters)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transforms/api/_incremental.py", line 257, in __call__
    return self._compute_func(**kwargs)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transforms/api/_transform.py", line 247, in compute
    self(**kwargs)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transforms/api/_transform.py", line 175, in __call__
    return self._compute_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowplow/datasets/derived/create_bad_events_size_violations.py", line 37, in compute
    df = df.withColumn("failure", F.col("data.failure"))
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 2478, in withColumn
    return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc), self.sql_ctx)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: No such struct field failure in
```

What am I missing out on?

I basically want to extract values for "actualSizeBytes" and "expectation" which are nested inside "failure" but so far, I am not even able to extract "failure" itself.

Comment: I checked your code and it works fine for me (Spark 3.4.0). Are you sure your value in data column is correct parsable json? Did you check `s = """{"failure":{"actualSizeBytes":206958, [...] }}"""; json.loads(s)` does not throw exception? Did you examine what `json_schema` contains?